# Save A Matplotlib Figure to A File Along with Displaying it on The Browser Django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I am very new to Django and the following is a detailed explanation of the problem I am trying to resolve using Django Python.

**Problem:-**

Upload a multiple csv files (**five files total**) and then take those files and construct five figures corresponding to the uploaded files. Finally, I want to have a single page in which I ask the user to upload the files and then the user will get a **conformational message for files uploaded successfully**. After that, the files should be displayed only if the user hit the graphing button and should display the five figures on the same webpage.

My attempt thus far:-

A snippet of My views.py:

```
def Upload(request):
  list_doc = []
  for count, x in enumerate(request.FILES.getlist('files')):
             def multifiles(f):
                    with open(dir_path + x.name + str(count) + ".csv" , 'wb+') as destination:
                            list_doc.append(x.name)
                            for chunk in f.chunks():
                                    destination.write(chunk)
             multifiles(x)

  docs = list_doc
  return render_to_response("myapp/mypage.html", {'upload_num':str(count+1)+" Files uploaded successfully!", "files_list":docs}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))


def graph(request):

 plt.figure(num)
 plt.plot(x,y, color =colorcurve, label=filename)
 ax = plt.subplot(111)
 ax.plot(x,y, color =colorcurve, linewidth=1.5)
 plt.legend(fontsize = 7.9, bbox_to_anchor=(0.61, 1), loc=6, borderaxespad=0.)
 file_saved = plt.savefig(dirpath+filename, format='png')
 figure = dirpath+filename+".png"
 return render_to_response("myapp/mypage.html", {'file_saved':figure},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**I am not sure what to use in urls.py? help please?**

In html:

```
        <body>
            <!-- Uplading files! -->
            <p><a href="{% url 'list' %}" align="right">Return to home</a></p>
            <p> Please, starting uploading your files <p>

                    <form action="{% url "UploadFile" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="file" name="files" multiple/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </form>

            <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <!-- input type="file" name="files" multiple/-->
                    <input type="submit" value="Graphing" />
            </form>
             <br>
             <div style="overflow:hidden;">
             {% load staticfiles %}


                    <img src="{% static "myapp/afile1-M1" %}" alt="My image" height="400" width="400" float=left hspace="30" border="1.8" />
```

When I runserver, it displays the graph into a new window. I want to do a couple of things. One, I want to save the figure into a file. Second, display it in the same browser window without the need to go to another window.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Made an update, we can move this to chat next.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
If you want to draw the graph only when "Graphing" is clicked, then name your input type, hence:

```
<input type="submit" value="Graphing" name="graphing"/>
```

and then you can check whether it has been clicked in your view:

```
if request.POST.get('graphing'):
#basically means "if user has clicked the graphing button"
```

Hope this helps,

---

Create two views:

```
def draw_pie(request):
    size = request.GET.get('size')
    return render(request, 'blog/draw_pie.html', {'size':size})

from pylab import figure, axes, pie, title
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
def pies (rquest, size):
    f = figure(figsize=(6,6))
    ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
    fracs = [15,size,45, 10]
    explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
    pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
    title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(f)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    matplotlib.pyplot.close(f)
    return response
```

The first one will contain the form, the second one will draw the graph.

Create two urls:

```
url(r'^pies/(?P<size>\d+)/$', views.pies, name='pies'),
    url(r'^draw_pie/$', views.draw_pie, name='draw_pie'),
```

The first one contains a parameter, or as many parameters as you like, to set the variables of the graph. I have set the size of one of the fracs in the pie chart.

The second one is the url for the form.

Create two templates, one empty one called `pies.html`:

```
empty
```

and one more template called `draw_pie.html`:

```
 <form method="GET" action="/draw_pie/">
            <h1>Pie Size</h1>

            <label>
                <span>Size: </span>
                <input type="number" step = "any" id="searchBox" class="input-medium search-query"
                name="size" placeholder="size"><br>
            </label>


            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Draw Pie" >
        </form>

        <img src="http://yourwebsite.com/pies/{{ size }}"><br>
```

This will give you this result:

[image]

If you change the size to 99 and click draw, it will reload the page and creates a new graph using the parameter you just input, then calls the graph directly using the img tag. You can see the parameter being passed in the url also:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: @aBiologist I will do an edit now, let me know if it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot  for the great explanation. The problem is when add the img tag, it displays the image either if I enter the size or not. Is it possible when I add the img tag without the size to display the image only if the user click on the draw image ? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Yes , you can wrap the img tag by an if statement that checks if size is not None. This will make sure to display image only if user has clicked draw. You can use if statement in django templates.

Comment: What if I don't use the size at all ? Is there another way to do so ?

Comment: If you don't want the size then why do you need the form ? You can just use a div tag to hide and display the image when you click the button. In this case you don't even have to reload the page because you aren't setting parameters . I'm using my phone right now, when I'm in a computer I will edit my answer.

Comment: What I do have in mind is to upload a multiple files which are already done. Use another form to take those uploaded files to draw graphs and displayed them only when a user clicked the graphing button. Hope it is clear, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123044/discussion-between-almost-a-beginner-and-abiologist).